# buscar un libro por titulo y devolver una coleccion de libros con ese titulo en java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase libros, una usuarios, una biblioteca y la principal y necesito hacer una busqueda de libro por titulo y devolver una array con los libros que tengan ese mismo titulo dejo el codigo por si alguien me da una mano. gracias

en la clase principal tengo un metodo que se llama buscarLibro

```
 private static void buscarLibro(Biblioteca b) {
         Scanner en= new Scanner(System.in);  
         String titulo;
         System.out.println("Ingrese el titulo del Libro: ");
         titulo=en.nextLine();
         
         Libro[] aux= b.buscar(titulo);
         if (aux != null){
             for (Libro aux1 : aux) {
                 System.out.println(aux1.ToString());
             }
         }else{
             System.out.println("No esxisten libros con ese titulo");
         }

que llama a la funcion buecar de la clase biblioteca y le pasa el titulo a buscar. 



  public Libro[] buscar( String titulo){
            int j=0;
            Libro librosBuscados[]=new Libro [libros.length];
            
            for (int i=0; i<libros.length;i++){
                
                if(libros[i].getTitulo().equals(titulo)){
                    
                        librosBuscados[j]=new Libro(libros[i].getTitulo(),
                        libros[i].getAutor(),libros[i].isDisponible());
                        j++;
                    }
                
                     
                }  
                         
                
            
            
            return librosBuscados;
            
           
        }
Este el metodo buscar que recibe el titulo recorre el array libros comprara los titulos y en teoria llena el array librosPrestados. pero cuando lo ejecuto me tira un error diciemdome que libros[i] es null. agradeceria un monton si alguien me puede ayudar donde me estoy equivocando.
```

Comment: Hola podrías mostrar en que parte estas llenando tu arreglo libros[]. Como extra podrias  agregar un if para verificar que no sea nula esa posicion. algo asi:

 for (int i=0; i<libros.length;i++){
                if(libro[i]!=null)
                if(libros[i].getTitulo().equals(titulo)){
                        librosBuscados[j]=new Libro(libros[i].getTitulo(),
                        libros[i].getAutor(),libros[i].isDisponible());
                        j++;
                    } 
                }

Comment: es medio confuso cómo está armado el código. pero me parece que el problema es que estás creando un array `librosBuscados` con el mismo tamaño que el array `libros`. luego utilizas un for para recorrer `libros` y según en la posición que tienes el libro que cumple las condiciones de búsqueda, lo estás asignando en el nuevo array que llamaste `librosBuscados`. Es decir, a menos que todos los elementos de `libros` cumplan con la condicion de búsqueda, el array a retornar, va a tener posiciones en `null`. Tal vez deberías ver de usar una lista en vez de un array

Comment: gracias si lo resolvi con arrayList